# make mydesign fill the asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an Asp.net page
my code is as

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="fisrt_page.aspx.cs" Inherits="my_project.fisrt_page" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login_style.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background: url(../images/demo/backgrounds/background_login.jpg);">

    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<......................my elements.....................>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my design looks like image below

https://plus.google.com/u/0/104984108592274133808/posts/4GdoUjboqi2?pid=6094624686097586866&oid=104984108592274133808

but I want that my design fill all the page and hide the spaces as images from my design
Sorry for my bad English
but please help me

my css was as

```
html, head, body, form {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}



.inputbox {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DDD inset;
    color: #666;
    outline: none;
    height: 25px;
    width: 275px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you will need to learn some basic css to do it

Comment: @charlietfl I have a CSS file , I did many classes style in it , but problem still exist

Comment: You need to provide us what you have tried with your CSS, otherwise we are just doing all the work for you. This is now what SO is for.

Comment: Are you looking to cover the entire page with an overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather in your post, you are trying to do a popup, and overlay your background with either a solid or transparent color. To achieve this you can do the following:

**Solid Color:**

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**Transparent Color:**

```
.overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /*dim the background*/
}
```

To activate this, you can change use jQuery to show the overlay:

```
<div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
<script>
    $('#overlay').show();
</script>
```

This of course would be best if you did it in a button click or some other action.

I hope this leads you in the right direction.